# Randomly distribute a set of string into a vector

Tags: r

Is there any function that randomly distributes a specific set of strings into a vector form? As an example,

```
Str <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
```

and I want to make `Str100` which contains 100 randomly distributed variables from `Str`, like `('A','B','A','D','C','E', .......... )`. What function is needed for this?

Also, is it possible to make it with same number of each variables in `Str`, like 20 `'A'` and 20 `'B'` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Str <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

> I want to make `Str100` which contains 100 randomly distributed variables from `Str`.

```
sample(Str, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
```

> Also, is it possible to make it with same number of each variables in `Str`.

```
## the outside `sample` is used to produce a random shuffle
sample(rep(Str, each = 20), replace = FALSE)
```

Read documentation `?sample` and `?rep` to learn more about these functions.